# Does a McCLIM Click Listener exist?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clim, mcclim

I have been trying to learn McCLIM and it has been quite difficult given the terseness of the documentation. After reading [the manual](https://franz.com/support/documentation/current/doc/clim-ug.pdf) I haven't been able to figure out how to associate a click to a pane and run a command. I am aware I can define commands such as:

```
(define-app-command (com-say :name t) ()
  (format t "Hello world!"))
```

And type `Say` into the command box to get it to do something. I would like to click a pane and have it output this hello world string when clicked.

What do I need to set up in order to enable click listeners on a given pane?

Comment: it's possible to do that. If you don't get answers here, it might be useful to ask on a mcclim mailing list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two ways you can do that. The first would be using `presentations` and `presentation-to-command-translator` and second would use gadgets (aka. widgets) like `push-button`. I guess you haven't learned about `presentations` yet, so I would show you how to do it with gadgets.

The below example would have a pane and a push button. when you click the button, you would see "Hello World!" output to the pane.

```lisp
;;;; First Load McCLIM, then save this in a file and load it.

(in-package #:clim-user)

(define-application-frame example ()
  ()
  (:panes
   (app :application
        :scroll-bars :vertical
        :width 400
        :height 400)
   (button :push-button
          :label "Greetings"
          :activate-callback
          (lambda (pane &rest args)
            (declare (ignore pane args))
            ;; In McCLIM, `t` or *standard-output is bound to the first pane of
            ;; type :application, in this case `app` pane.
            (format t "Hello World!~%" ))))
  (:layouts
   (default (vertically () app button))))

(defun run ()
  (run-frame-top-level (make-application-frame 'example)))

(clim-user::run)
```

---

*P.S.* One way to learn how to do something in McCLIM is to run and look at `clim-demos`. Once you find something interesting and want to know how it is done, look at its source in `Examples` directory of McCLIM source.

For Help, it is much better to use IRC chat (#clim on libera.chat) where multiple McCLIM devs hang out.

---

**EDIT:** Second example with `presentation-to-command-translator`, clicking anywhere in the pane would output "Hello World!" in the pane.

```lisp
(in-package #:clim-user)

(define-application-frame example ()
  ()
  (:pane :application
   :width 400
   :display-time nil))

;; Note the `:display-time nil` option above, without it default McCLIM command-loop
;; will clear the pane after each time the command is run. It wasn't needed in previous
;; example because there were no commands involved.

(define-example-command (com-say :name t)
    ()
  (format t "Hello World!~%"))

(define-presentation-to-command-translator say-hello
    (blank-area com-say example :gesture :select)
    (obj)
  nil)

(defun run ()
  (run-frame-top-level (make-application-frame 'example)))

(clim-user::run)
```

Comment: This is a fantastic example of gadgets but would you mind setting up an example that corresponds to a click signal on the pane? Happy to green check after that.

Comment: I've updated my answer with second example.